# How can I use a DBLookupComboBox to select a foreign key value without immediately changing the target table? (Delphi 5 Pro)

Tags: delphi, combobox, foreign-keys, delphi-5

Basic Scenario:

1. User clicks 'edit item'
2. Edit dialog opens
3. A combobox 'item type' should be populated with items form a table 'item_type'. The combobox should display 'item_type.name', but also know about 'item_type.id'
4. User edits other item stuff and selects an item type, then clicks ok
5. My program does some input validation
6. if everything is ok, get the 'item_type.id' from the selected combo item and save it to the foreign key column of the item table ('item.fk_item_type').

If I understand this component correctly, I should set DataSource to point to the destination table 'item' and DataField to 'item.fk_item_type'. But that would immediately edit my item table before I get a chance the validate all the other input.

It feels like I am missing something here. Somewhere I read that I need to use a classic ComboBox and fill it manually. But then I don't understand how to get to the id of the selected item.

Thank you for any pointers.

Edit:
I am starting to suspect that maybe I am missing a fundamental thing. All these DB* components, do they load values from that database automatically, but I have to call Post() myself? Meaning they do not automatically change values in the database?

Comment: You could add an OnValidate - Event to your `item.fk_item_type` field

Comment: a claasic ComboBox could be filled with Items.AddObject(DisplayText,TObject(ID)) ... but you also can use TDBlookupComboBox without assigning Datasource and Datafield and use the property KeyValue for manual assignment to item.fk_item_type.

Comment: @bummi I don't see where I can 'add an event to my field'. Are you talking about a database trigger? I am not seeing an event named 'OnValidate' in the list of events for DBLookupComboBox.

Comment: @bummi I didn't know about Items.AddObject, that sounds interesting. I already tried not assigning the DataSource/DataField, but then nothing is ever displayed in the edit field (just in the dropdown list).

Comment: The property can be found on your field in the dataset

Comment: Not seeing it. I am using TDataSource and TADOTable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30901/discussion-between-bummi-and-zalumon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use a DBLookupComboBox. You have to supply values for the following properties

- datasource - linked to the table which you are editing, presumably 'items'
- datafield - the name of the field in the table which you are editing, presumably 'item_type'
- listsource - linked to the table which populated the combobox, presumably 'item_types'
- list field - the name of the field from 'item_types' which you want to display, presumably 'name'
- key field - the name of the field from 'item_types' which will be inserted into the items record, presumably 'item_type'

The table which populated the combobox is never edited.

You can validate the values before posting the new/edited 'items' record.

I can show you how to use a non-data aware combobox if necessary, but it's easier to use the data aware version.

Regarding validation, I use the following code template in edit dialogs.

```
Function TEditQuestion.Execute (n: longint): boolean;
var
 gen: longint;

begin
 sdsEditQuestion.params[0].asinteger:= n;  // TSQLDataSet
 with qEditQuestion do                     // TClientDataSet
  begin
   open;
   if n = -1 then                          // new record
    begin
     caption:= 'New record';
     insert;
     fieldbyname ('alive').asinteger:= 1;
     // initialise necessary fields in the dataset
    end
   else caption:= 'Editing record ' + inttostr (n);

   edit;
   if showmodal = mrOK then
    begin
     // validation code comes here. Set 'result' to true if everything is ok
     if result then
      begin
       if n = -1 then
        begin
         with qGenID do
          begin
           open;
           gen:= fields[0].asinteger;    // get new value from generator
           close
          end;

         FieldByName ('id').asinteger:= gen;
        end;
       post;
       applyupdates (0)
      end
     else cancel  // showmodal = OK, result = false
   else           // showmodal cancelled
    begin
     cancel;
     result:= false
    end;
  end             // with qEditQuestion
 end;
```

Comment: I'm not fixed on using DBLookupComboBox, just whatever is easiest to achieve my task. Are you saying the datasource table is not changed when the user makes a selection?

Comment: @Zalumon: the table is changed only after you post the changes. Normally this occurs after the user presses the OK button on your edit dialog. You can validate data in the OKBtnClick event *before* posting the data. I'll add some code to my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Ah that's great, this probably solves my 'problem'. No need for code, that's what I wanted to do anyway.

Comment: @Zalumon: If my answer solves your problem, could you please mark it as the selected answer.

Comment: Of course, it just took me the whole day to actually test this.